# Tkinter и widget focus Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, ui

Необходимо **избавится от фокуса на виджетах в tkinter**. Можно переключать его каждый раз на root, но делать это с каждым widget не рационально.

**Конкретика**
На картинке можете видеть точки вокруг надписи. Их надо **замаскировать**.
[image: Точки вокруг слова "Folders"]

Это не критично в таком обьеме, как на изображении выше, но когда происходит что-то похожее, как на скриншоте ниже, надо что-то делать.
[image: Скришеот 2 - актуальная проблема]

Во втором примере используется тема **azure dark**. Под нее и нужно решение. В будущем такие же операции надо будет делать с другими компонентами. Что использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Для управления внешнего вида виджета используются стили и темы. Просто при фокусе изменяется форма виджета по макету разработанному программистами - windows, linux или mac. Но если вы возьметесь за это дело, будьте готовы к разным подводным камням и к разработке минимум трех разных вариантов для основных oc, так как все виджеты "собраны" по разному (даже на одной oc, но в разных темах!). И да прибудет с вами сила! Для начала рекомендую почитать  https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html